# Bulk-convert shortcuts to target

Tags: windows-10, script, file-shortcut

(Windows10) Sometimes I need to create a subset of a master photos folder, but I am trying to be cute and save space by creating the SUBSETFOLDER somewhere, then selecting the pictures I want, right-clicking one of the files and dragging this subset to SUBSETFOLDER.  When I release the mouse button, I choose to "create shortcuts" which in effect creates shortcuts to all the selected files.

That works as intended, I can then goto SUBSETFOLDER, click on one of the shortcuts and the picture appears.  I can even right-arrow and peruse the other pictures without issues.

Presuming I now wanted to send the actual files to a photo-printing company or put them on a USB stick, is there a script/utility/trick to convert these shortcuts to the actual pictures so I can copy them to the USB stick?  (Apologies if that has been resolved before, I saw a similar thread but it seemed overly-complicated for doing something similar it looked like.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished in **PowerShell** using the [`wscript.shell`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh) COM object, which, among other things, contains methods for reading, creating, and modifiying `.lnk` files.

This is "bare-bones" with no verifiction of paths or error trapping, focusing on the logic. If this is a frequent operation, this code could for the basis for a reusable function.

```
$SubsetFolder  = 'C:\<Path to folder containing .lnk shortcut files>'
$Destination   = '<Path to copy destination>'

$WshShell      = New-Object -com wscript.shell

Get-ChildItem $SubsetFolder *.lnk |
    ForEach-Object {
        ( $WshShell.CreateShortcut( $_.FullName )).TargetPath |
            Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -WhatIf
    }
```

[`ForEach-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1) processes each file in `$SubsetFolder`.

Note that [`Copy-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) is using the `-WhatIf` parameter. This allows you to preview the copy action without actually copying the files --- useful for verifying only desired files are being processed. Delete the parameter to acutually copy the files.